# Flexible flat cable AWM 20798 female connector? (16 pin/1mm pitch)

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable

Where can I buy a female connector for a [AWM ribbon flex cable 1.00 mm pitch 16 pin](http://cgi.ebay.com/AWM-RIBBON-FLEX-CABLE-1-00-mm-pitch-16-PIN-230-mm-16PIN-/320662694046?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4aa8fc689e). Its about 17.00 mm wide. I need this for connecting this cable to a patch panel with 2.54 mm spacing.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for are called FFC, FPC (Flat Flexible) connectors.  It looks like DigiKey has quite a few at 0.039" (1.0mm) pitch and 16 conductor.

If you have a surface mount 1mm plug, this is what you need:
http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=3400022

If you use a through hole 1mm plug, you need something like this (much cheaper and easier):
http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=3800027

Never dealt with this company, so this isn't an endorsement.  You may find more by searching for Pitch Changer.

Comment: Digikey tould me that there is no connector from FFC 1mm pitch to patch panel with 2.54mm spacing. What actually makes sense.

Comment: I've seen some break out boards for 1mm to 2.54mm.  This is often used for LCD displays.  Are you putting this into a 0.1" protoboard or something?

Comment: Joe, yes a 2.54 mm spacing bread board.

Answer (score 1):

I found something at [digikey](http://digikey.de), since there is no URL for search results these are the steps to reproduce my results:

1. http://digikey.de
2. Search for "FFC"
3. Click "FFC, FPC (flach, flexibel) - Steckverbinder - Kartenmontage (X items)"
4. Select then Positionsanzahl: 16
5. and Neigung (pitch): 1mm
6. and Montagetyp: Durchführungsloch, Durchführungsloch rechtwinklig, Kartenrand Ausschnitt
7. and select "Artikel auf Lager"
8. then click "Filter anwenden"
9. If the product list does not show up select "Seite aufrufen"
10. In the column "Einheitspreis" click the ascending icon and enter 10 for "Teilemenge (erforderlich)" since I'm looking for at least 10 connectors, sorted by the cheapest.

Update: Digikey told me that there is flex cable 1mm connector for 2.54 mm bread board. :(